# How to get only one data value from a multi-value map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a Map (java.util.Map) that contains types int and Serializer (a custom type). the object "typeA" is a superclass of Serializer and the getSerializerValues() method returns a map of Serializers and Integers. I want to only get the ints from each position in the map and save them into an array. How can I do this?

```
  Map<Serializer, Integer> serializers = typeA.getSerializerValues();
  int[] values = new int[serializers.size()];
//how to get JUST the ints from each position in the map and save them into the int array “values”?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `values()` method.

```
public Collection<V> values()
```

Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29

Comment: now how do i get the ints from this Collection into an array

Comment: The other answer by @MartinS has the code you need to turn the collection into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways how you can get the values from the map as an array:

First the Java 7 way:

```
int[] values = new int[serializers.size()];
int i = 0;
for(int value : serializers.values()) {
    values[i++] = value;
}
```

Second the Java 8 way:

```
int[] values = serializers.values().stream().mapToInt(x -> x).toArray();
```

Comment: what's that for loop with a colon? I thought you could only have for(assignment operator, test condition, increment operator)

Comment: @JavaWeenis it's called an [Enhanced For-Loop](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/480-the-enhanced-for-loop.html) and it just iterates over all elements in an `Iterable` like collections or arrays.